# sql query in orange datamining software

Tags: sql, postgresql, orange

When I am trying to run a SQL query in orange datamining software using select statement and postgres database, it returns an error

> INVALID CONNECTION OPTION 'PASSWD'

My query looks like this:

```
select * from CFAR_K7_DBTF_ALL;
```

Comment: Your connection to the database is messed up.  it has nothing to do with your sql query.

Comment: I have not used postgresql before. I have created database postgres  with username postgres and password *******. Also created table  with name cfre_hs_dbtf_all and load data to it.  Now using these credentials, I am trying to establish connection to the postgres database from Orange. I have selected following options in Orange while writing SQL query as mentioned above : Type : Postgres,  Host : localhost, Username : postgres, Password : *******, Database : postgres. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Your error message says that your connection string is trying to use 'PASSWD' instead of 'PASSWORD' to connect to the db.

Comment: I have used different password not 'PASSWORD'. So there is no question of that mistake.

Comment: PASSWORD is the name of the password variable.

Answer (score 0):

This error is still valid, while there is 4 years old open ticket: http://old.biolab.si/trac/ticket/1218

I made this change to make it work:

```
--- Orange\data\sql.py
+++ (clipboard)
@@ -106,6 +106,7 @@
             }
         if schema == 'postgres':
             argTrans["database"] = "dbname"
+            argTrans["password"] = "password"
         elif schema == 'odbc':
             argTrans["host"] = "server"
             argTrans["user"] = "uid"
```